# Nginx Reverse Proxy: What difference between a slash included in the pathname or not?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I try to use Nginx to proxy local port, just like:

```
location /name {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

and I lost slash for the first time like above. I try to use `mydomain.com/name` to visit. I can open the page but can't load other source files. I look up Chrome console, I found the source files want to use `mydomain.com/source/style.css` to load, not `mydomain.com/name/source/style.css`

**If I try to add a `/` at pathname, like:**

```
location /name/ {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

It works well!

**So, what difference between the above two?**

#### Add question

If I use alias, such as:

```
location /static {
        alias /mypath/static/;
}
```

or

```
location /static {
        alias /mypath/static;
}
```

Dose the above two have differences?

Answer (score 0):

That's unfortunately how relative URLs work. Since the / indicates a new directory or URI segmentation, your assets would get loaded from the `/name/` directory. But in the case of accessing it via `/name`, your assets will be loaded from the root URL as the browser believes the files are local to it.

Comment: So, that's why Nginx uses `location / {...}` as the root URL. The slash is indispensable.